# Stack Overflow Userpic generation (Identicons)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, gravatar

i an creating a website in C# ASP.NEt and want to use a feature similar to Stack Overflow,
Every time a new user registers on the StackOverflow.com he is assigned a default user picture until he has a gravatar, Now every picture is different from the previous one, so it is sure it is generated, i want to know how can this be done in C#.

Note: (I don't think it is a meta question so please don't move it there)

Comment: @zerkms you mean those weird  patterns are given by gravatar

Comment: yes. If you don't upload any custom userpic to a gravatar.com - it generates one for you.

Comment: You might be interested also in http://unicornify.appspot.com/use-it It generates colorful ponies in a similar way.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's called [Identicions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identicon). They are images generated by some kind of hash, usually on a username or email.

There is a nice, open source library, on Codeplex for generating Identicons. More info [here](http://identicon.codeplex.com/).

Edit: You can actually use gravatar to generate Identicons. Construct a URL like this:

http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/HASH_HERE?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG

Comment: Obviously gravatar generates hash based on email.

Comment: Yep, i know. Did not know StackOverflow used gravatar for the Identicons.

Comment: http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/a63e9bcbecb716d9be2031db853229bd?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG - why did not you just look at the OPs identicon image src? ;-)