# Generating uniqe security images for users in .NET

Tags: .net, security

We want to show users a unique image generated for them each time they login. Is there a good .NET library we can use to do this?

We're trying to assign each user a unique image and show it to them while they're logging in. So that they can know if/when they are on a phishing site.

Answer (score 0):

Consider looking at the way StackOverflow does it; using [identicons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identicon).

It's basically an image created based on a hash value (for example using the email or user name).

See also:

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17443/how-is-the-default-user-avatar-generated

[StackOverflow Userpic generation (Identicons)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4509660/stackoverflow-userpic-generation-identicons)

Comment: I did. But we found identicons too hard to be remembered. User can easily confuse one with the other. I found this project that generates unique monsters but it doesn't have a .net implementation: http://www.splitbrain.org/projects/monsterid

Answer (score 0):

My bank website does this, however, it simply has a list of predefined images. It presented me a random image from that list when I created my account. It also allowed me to pick (change) the image to one of my liking by presenting me 8 different images. There are obviously more than 8 images in the library as each time I go to change my security image, the 8 images I get to choose from are different.

Also, it forced me to create a security phrase. It displays both the image and the phrase on the page where I enter my password.

Doesn't seem too complicated. 9999 images would get you the same security as a standard 4 digit PIN.

Comment: I thought about doing this but creating a unique image sounded better. The reason is because if we used a library with 10k images, someone doing a phishing attack would be successful 1 in every 10.000 users even if they only knew just one image of the library. Assuming they reach a few thousand users, there would be a non-negligible chance that they would be successful. This is assuming that we can stop them from scrapping the image from the site. We're working on that too.

Comment: @AntonAnsgar, Consider doing the phrase too then. I don't see how you're going to randomly generate an image that the user will remember. Maybe let them draw their own.